# Why I cannot see the number of people who earned badges "Constable" and "Precognitive"

Tags: discussion, badges, visibility

I took a look at this place: [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

I would like to know, why I cannot see the number of people who has been prized with "Constable" and "Precognitive" badges?

> [image: Precognitive]
>
> [image: Constable]

Nobody has been prized so far? Do I need any special credentials or it is just a problem with my web browser?

Comment: Because nobody has them.

Comment: Since stackoverflow didn't go through Area51, Precognitive has never been awarded. It didn't have temporary moderators in beta either, so Constable didn't get awarded either.

Answer (score 5):

> Why I cannot see the number of people who has been prized with
>   "Constable" and "Precognitive" badges?

Because it **Awarded 0 times** and you don't need any special credentials for this and also not the web browser issue.

Answer (score 5):

Those badges have **never been awarded on Stack Overflow**, because that site did not come from Area 51, [which came long after Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/), and did not have pro-tem moderators, [which also came long after Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).